# How do i click on elements in a cross domain iframe?

Tags: iframe, same-origin-policy

There is a domain that i am registered to,and that domain uses a frame to load contents for users to click on.The frame source is a subdomain of the main domain.let's say the main domain is "example.com" and the subdomain is "store.example.com" .My aim is to write a code that will do the clicking for me.

At first i used JavaScript then i moved to Jquery hoping to get the problem solved but the problem persists.

```
    $zero = $('div.nodeClassName').eq(0);
    //caching children of the above node
    $zeroChildZero = $zero.children().eq(0);
    $zeroChildOne = $zero.children().eq(1);
    //clicks either first child or second child
    $zeroChildZero || $zeroChildOne.click();
```

JavaScript returned undefined while JQuery couldn't find any object in the document but the object exists.How do i go about this problem?